# Unable to add new rule in Storage Management Policy on Azure

Tags: azure, lifecycle, azure-cli

I am using `az` cli to add a `storage management-policy` to delete the blobs in the containers whose modification time is more than 7 days.
Here is the `policy.json` file:

```
  "rules": [
    {
      "name": "expirationRule1",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [ "blockBlob" ],
          "prefixMatch": [ "container1" ]
        },
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 7 }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I create this lifecycle management policy using the command:

```
az storage account management-policy create --account-name <my_acc_name> --policy <policy_file> --resource-group <my_res_group>
```

This step succeeds. Now I want to add another policy on a different container. The `policy.json` remains same with `prefixMatch` changed to `container2` and `name` changed to `expirationRule2`. Now when I apply this new policy with the same command mentioned above, I cannot see the older policy applied, but can only see the new policy.
Here are the steps:

```
$az storage account management-policy create --account-name resacc1 --resource-group resgrp1 --policy /tmp/azure_lifecycle.json

{
  "id": "<some_id_here>",
  "lastModifiedTime": "2021-05-10T10:10:32.261245+00:00",
  "name": "DefaultManagementPolicy",
  "policy": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "definition": {
          "actions": {
            "baseBlob": {
              "delete": {
                "daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan": null,
                "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 7.0
              },
              "enableAutoTierToHotFromCool": null,
              "tierToArchive": null,
              "tierToCool": null
            },
            "snapshot": null,
            "version": null
          },
          "filters": {
            "blobIndexMatch": null,
            "blobTypes": [
              "blockBlob"
            ],
            "prefixMatch": [
              "container1"                                << container1 is prefixMatch
            ]
          }
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "expirationRule1",
        "type": "Lifecycle"
      }
    ]
  },
  "resourceGroup": "resgrp1",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies"
}
```

Now I add new policy with container2:

```
$ az storage account management-policy create --account-name resacc1 --resource-group resgrp1 --policy /tmp/azure_lifecycle.json
{
  "id": "<some_id_here>",
  "lastModifiedTime": "2021-05-10T10:11:54.622184+00:00",
  "name": "DefaultManagementPolicy",
  "policy": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "definition": {
          "actions": {
            "baseBlob": {
              "delete": {
                "daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan": null,
                "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 7.0
              },
              "enableAutoTierToHotFromCool": null,
              "tierToArchive": null,
              "tierToCool": null
            },
            "snapshot": null,
            "version": null
          },
          "filters": {
            "blobIndexMatch": null,
            "blobTypes": [
              "blockBlob"
            ],
            "prefixMatch": [
              "container2"                                    << container2 in prefixMatch
            ]
          }
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "expirationRule2",
        "type": "Lifecycle"
      }
    ]
  },
  "resourceGroup": "resgrp1",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies"
}
```

Now after applying the 2 rules, when I do a show command it only shows that a single policy is applied on the storage account.

```
$ az storage account management-policy show --account-name resacc1 --resource-group resgrp1
{
  "id": "<some_id_here>",
  "lastModifiedTime": "2021-05-10T10:11:54.622184+00:00",
  "name": "DefaultManagementPolicy",
  "policy": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "definition": {
          "actions": {
            "baseBlob": {
              "delete": {
                "daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan": null,
                "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 7.0
              },
              "enableAutoTierToHotFromCool": null,
              "tierToArchive": null,
              "tierToCool": null
            },
            "snapshot": null,
            "version": null
          },
          "filters": {
            "blobIndexMatch": null,
            "blobTypes": [
              "blockBlob"
            ],
            "prefixMatch": [
              "container2"
            ]
          }
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "expirationRule2",
        "type": "Lifecycle"
      }
    ]
  },
  "resourceGroup": "resgrp1",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies"
}
```

Can someone please help me out on knowing how to append a new rule to an already existing policy OR create a new policy all together, so that I have both the rules applied on the containers in my storage account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at AZ CLI documentation, the only options available to you are either [`creating a new policy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/management-policy?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_management_policy_create) or [`updating an existing policy (i.e. replacing a policy completely)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/management-policy?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_management_policy_update). No command is available to add a rule to an existing policy.

The reason you're seeing the behavior is because you're updating the entire policy which is overriding the previous policy contents.

What you would need to do is modify your policy.json file and include both rules and then update the policy on the storage account. Or you could get the existing policy using [`az storage account management-policy show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/management-policy?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_management_policy_show), parse the policy JSON, add new rule and then update the policy using [`az storage account management-policy update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/management-policy?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_management_policy_update).

Comment: Hello Gaurav, thanks for the detailed answer, however I am able to add another policy using the Azure UI, so I am not sure why it can't be done using the CLI.

Comment: The one which I tried was adding a whole new policy as can be seen in the examples as well (with diff names and container filter). At the end I expected 2 different policies. Am I missing anything there?

Comment: The documentation does not explicitly state this but I think you can have only one policy per storage account. Each policy can have multiple rules. The reason I say this is there is no `List Policies` REST API operation mentioned here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/managementpolicies.

Comment: Not sure, but if I add 2 policies through UI and run a 'az storage account management-policy show' command, it lists BOTH the policies applied. Looks like documentation on az cli should be more updated with examples.

Comment: I think you’re confusing “Rule” with “Policy”. In Portal, you add multiple rules. There’s no option to add multiple policies.

Comment: Yes, it's rule. Checked it on portal. Thanks Gaurav