# Azure Lifecycle setting in BICEP delete/replace all the existing rules

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

So I create following bicep based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2022-05-01/storageaccounts/managementpolicies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep.

It works fine and creates rule, however it deletes all the existing rules. Even they are more than one rule (all different names of course), it delete all the existing rules and replace it with one rule in the bicep script. What am I missing?

```
resource storage_lifecycle 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies@2022-05-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  parent:storageAccount
  properties: {
    policy: {
      rules: [
        {
        name: 'lifeCycleRule'
        enabled: true
        type: 'Lifecycle'
        definition: {
          filters: {
            blobTypes: [
              'blockBlob'
              ]
            }
            actions: {
              baseBlob: {
                tierToCool: {
                  daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: 30
                }
                tierToArchive: {
                  daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: 30
                }
                delete: {
                  daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: 30
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this stack answer: [Unable to add new rule in Storage Management Policy on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67469229/8948656), and my experience with Azure API Gateway, you will need to add the existing rules to the new policy.

Comment: Yeah I read that post. I guess there is no way to do that for now.